# installing komozer on fedora 18 ?

Tags: installation, fedora

i have download kompozer and installed by following step:

~> sudo yum install compat-libstdc++-33

~> sudo cp ~/Download/kompozer-077-i686.tgz /usr/local/src/kompozer/

~> cd /usr/local/src/kompozer

~> sudo tar vfzx kompozer-077-i686.tgz

~> sudo rm kompozer-077-i686.tgx
~> sudo mv kompozer kompozer-077

~> sudo ln -s /usr/local/src/kompozer/kompozer-077/kompozer /usr/local/bin/.

~> source ~/.tcshrc

on running this command

~> kompozer &

i application doesn't start and got an error on terminal  :

[root@HyperWorkstation kompozer]# /usr/local/src/kompozer/kompozer-077/run-mozilla.sh: 
/usr/local/src/kompozer/kompozer-077/kompozer-bin: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

please help what goes wrong actually i feel bad may happened in .tcshrc file

........... thanx for reply in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
# yum install ld-linux.so.2
```

or

```
$ tar xvzf kompozer-0.8b3.es-ES.gcc4.2-i686.tar.gz
$ cd kompozer
$ ./kompozer-bin
```